# Get accurate distance between 2 GPS coordinates xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, gps, haversine

**Overview**

I am creating mobile application using xamarin c# which requires to get points in given range (3 meters). There are multiple points with latitude and longitude and what i need to do is to:

- Get `currentPosition` where I am standing from the cellphone
- Find the distance between `currentPosition`(cell GPS) and other multiple points
- Show the ones which comes under given range (3 meters is the requirement)

====================================================================

**What I have done:**

- To get the `currentPosition` ,I am using `plugin geolocator`. On its `positionChanged()`, it is setting the `currentPosition` variable which I am using(this is continuosly running and changing `currentPosition`)
- To get the distance between `currentPosition` and other fixed points , I am using `HaversineFormula`
- And then fetching those which comes under 3 meters of distance

=============================================================

**Problems I am Facing**

- As the `currentPosition` is being changed continously , latitude and longitude are sometimes less precised(7 digits after decimal) and sometimes highly precised(15 digits), and when the distance is calculated , it makes a huge diffrence. Even I am not moving my mobile device (static), it is still continuously updating `currentPosition`.
- It is not showing nearby points even they are in less than 1 meter range. Is there any issue with the `HaversineFormula`?

How can I control `current position` when the device is static?

I  have tested the whole code outside the building and terrace to get better results, but unable to solve this.

Comment: Just a quick comment, you know that gps accuracy has a possible error of at least 3 meters?. So finding objects in a 3 meter range i think is not going to work all the time...

Comment: and what is the maximum error?I am ready to change the radius from 3 meters to 10 meters , but still distance is not accurate

Comment: Not an expert on this at all, so it may not be possible, but can you filter the data before it changes your position variable? If so, this sounds like the classic use case of a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).

Comment: Accuracy is going to vary from phone to phone and from GPS receiver chipset to chipset within the "same" model. The GPS antennas in phones are cheap and a 15 meters "accuracy" across the world is a "safe" assumption (will it be better than that, yes, usually, but to *guarantee* it you need external antennas). You will need to filter and smooth the "raw" results to maintain a steady location....

Comment: For such small distances, haversine usage is like using a yardstick to measure the width of a blade of glass... as @jcb pointed out using algorithms such a a Kalman filter will help stablize your position and then you can apply haversine after that is required...

Comment: @SushiHangover I have nno idea about the kalman filter and how am I going to apply this into my logic

Answer (score 1):

Just an update.. am able to get nearbypoints.
the problem was in fetching current position using geolocator. I dont know why it doesn't work for me in getting current location coordinates, but the error rate was so high.
Anyway now I have implemented Google play services fused location apis to fetch location and its giving high accuracy.

So anybody if you want to implement such kind of feature, you can go for this api